# Can I connect more than one IR receiver to an Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, ir

I want to use `#include <IRremote.h>` to receive information from an infrared remote control. It works perfectly with one IR receiver.

But I want to put three or four IR receivers:

```
IRrecv irrecv6(pin6);
IRrecv irrecv7(pin7);
IRrecv irrecv8(pin8);
IRrecv irrecv9(pin9);
IRrecv irrecv10(pin10);
```

And:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv6.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
  irrecv7.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
  irrecv8.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
  irrecv9.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
  irrecv10.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}
```

Inside the loop function, I am checking each pin to see if there is any data received. But only the last pin (which means pin 10 above) is receiving the data and others are not.

Comment: you can connect multiple receivers, but why?

Comment: But always only one of them, which is initialized last, is receiving the Data.

Comment: @jsotola you could use it to get a very coarse sense of the direction the signal came from.

Comment: did you find the solution, because i also want to put 4 ir receiver on Arduino in my fyp. if you have a solution plz help mee.

Comment: Try my link
https://github.com/gerivega/Arduino-IRremote I wanted to do the same thing. I modified the latest library to incorporate the changes done by a previous programmer neco777.

Answer (score 3):

That library only supports one IR receiver at a time. Try [this fork](https://github.com/Neco777/Arduino-IRremote) that seems to have added multiple receivers support.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some delay between irrecv.decode()s and everything will work just fine.